# Update an existing string in a file

Tags: java, io, java-io

I have to edit the existing file named root.propertis and update it without saving in to another file

Following  is the sample proprety file.

```
root.label.getmore=Mehr Apps
root.msg.apps=Apps 
root.label.2.2=Coupons
root.label.35.2=MSNBC
root.label.43.2=PBS Kids
root.label.47.2=Yahoo! Digest
```

I have to update the string in the file  `"root.label.43.2=PBS Kids" to "root.label.43.2=Updated"`

But i need to save in the same file (root.propertis )by repalcing the string `root.label.43.2=PBS Kids`.No need to update the changes in another properties file.

Comment: "update it without saving in to another file".  A very, very bad idea.  Usually, we save to another file and then do two renames so that the original file is renamed to be a backup and the new file is renamed to have the original name.  Please revise your question to use this "make a new file and rename it" approach.

Comment: yes i tried using the method you said.but unable to delete a root.properties file.

Comment: i used File f1 = new File("C:\\Equinox\\UIDesign\\root\\root.properties");
   boolean success=f1.delete(); it returns false

Comment: but in case of a text file it is succesful

Comment: "unable to delete a root.properties".  That would be a separate question.  Please ask that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use java.util.Properties:

```
File f = new File("root.properties");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(fis);
fis.close();

p.setProperty("root.label.43.2", "Updated");
```

The call `p.store()` to save to a file.

Note exception handling has been omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following sequence to change [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) load the properties with `load(),` `setProperty(key,value)` and finally call `store()` to write it back.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing a .properties file can easily be achieved by using the `Properties` class (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)).

So you can

1. Read the file into a `Properties` instance using the `Properties#load` method
2. Update the `Properties` instance using the `Properties#setProperty` method
3. Write the `Properties` to file using the `Properties#store` method